# Deleting files from SVN

Tags: linux, svn

I've deleted files from my project using `svn del /path/project/file` on my server and the file was deleted from the server after an `svn commit`. However, when I type `svn list` in that directory, the files are still there in the repository, which is annoying as it interferes with any future `svn update` statements.

Why is it doing this and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit weird. You delete directly on the server (using server url and no commit) or you delete from your working copy and commit. For the first, `svn up` should remove the files from your working copy. In the second, they should already be gone from the working copy.

Comment: Can you give us your command sequence? Either you did the delete directly from the repository (which is possible), but then you don't need a commit. Or you deleted the files from your work directory, did a commit and then did an `svn ls` on your working directory again. Maybe you can try an `svn update` to update to the latest revision, then try `svn list` again?

Comment: My command was "svn del file" on the server itself, which deleted the file. svn update on server and working copy just said "target path does not exist". The files are still in the repository with svn list so how do I get rid of them from there.

Comment: Basically I want to delete the whole project from svn and start again

Comment: I also tried svn del file on working copy then svn commit. But when doing svn up on server it says "target path does not exist"

Comment: I've SOLVED this now, I just did a fresh svn import on server, and then svn checkout on both server and working copy and it's all fine now. Previous attempt got messed up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you updated the repo from a working copy on the server, and then expected the client working copy to magically update to the new revision. It doesn't, your client will show the version of the repo at the point it was checked out.

To "re-point" your client, you just need to update it (svn update) and it will fetch changes and then the repo browser will show you the latest version, not the one you currently have checked out.